# How can I implement a pub/sub pattern using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Is there any way to have a pub/sub pattern using `multiprocessing` data structures? In other words, I would like to have something like a queue, except that the publisher can send a single command to multiple workers simultaneously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create your own data structure to implement a simple pub/sub pattern using a wrapper around `multiprocessing.Queue`:

```
import os
import multiprocessing
from functools import wraps


def ensure_parent(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.getpid() != self._creator_pid:
            raise RuntimeError("{} can only be called in the "
                               "parent.".format(func.__name__))
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class PublishQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queues = []
        self._creator_pid = os.getpid()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__
        self_dict['_queues'] = []
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)

    @ensure_parent
    def register(self):
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self._queues.append(q)
        return q

    @ensure_parent
    def publish(self, val):
        for q in self._queues:
            q.put(val)

def worker(q):
    for item in iter(q.get, None):
        print("got item {} in process {}".format(item, os.getpid()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = PublishQueue()
    processes = []
    for _ in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(q.register(),))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    q.publish('1')
    q.publish(2)
    q.publish(None)  # Shut down workers

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Output:

```
got item 1 in process 4383
got item 2 in process 4383
got item 1 in process 4381
got item 2 in process 4381
got item 1 in process 4382
got item 2 in process 4382
```

This pattern will work well as long as the parent process is the only one doing the publishing, and you register a subscription queue for each worker in the parent, and then pass that subscription queue to the worker process using its `multiprocessing.Process` constructor. These limitations are due to `multiprocessing.Queue` being unpicklable. If you need to pass the subscription queue to an already running worker, you'll need to tweak the implementation to use a `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue` instead.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  It seems like this answers the question.

Comment: @Twirrim Neither am I! Such is life, though.

Comment: Aren't the Queues pickle-able if they are Manager Queues since then they are just references?

Comment: @CpILL Yep - the last sentence of my answer mentions that.