# How can I share a queue among three or more processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have three processes. One process reads data from disk. The other two processes do some calculation based on the data which is read by the first process.
The following code is my sketch:

```
def read(pathList, q):
    for path in pathList:
        q.put(readFunc(path))
    q.put(None)
    return


def calc0(src_q, des_q):
    while True:
        data = src_q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        else:
            des_q.put(calcFunc0(data))
    return


def calc1(src_q, des_q):
    while True:
        data = src_q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        else:
            des_q.put(calcFunc1(data))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as m:
        dataQueue = m.queue()
        res0 = m.queue()
        res1 = m.queue()
        readProcess = Process(target=read, args=(readPathList, dataQueue))
        readProcess.start()
        calcProcess0 = Process(target=calc0, args=(dataQueue, res0))
        calcProcess0.start()
        calcProcess1 = Process(target=calc1, args=(dataQueue, res1))
        calcProcess1.start()
        readProcess.join()
        calcProcess0.join()
        calcProcess1.join()
```

However, the above code has a serious problem: I CAN'T GET THE DATA FROM THE QUEUE TWICE! So, how can I share the data in the queue to three or more processes?

Comment: You should implement a pub-sub pattern data structure base on `multiprocessing.Queue`. A simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283647/15174775

Comment: Like @HALF9000 I too would consider pub/sub. I'd probably consider MQTT or Redis.

Comment: Redis and MQTT examples here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914945/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment offered by HALF9000 (using a `multiprocessing.Queue`) is an improvement over a *managed* queue and there is a lot to be said for Mark Setchell's comment about going the Redis route if you will be doing a lot of this type of publish/subscribe work and you want something really robust. But that is a quite a bit to bite of off for a possibly one-off situation.

I believe the best-performing solution uses the under-utilized `multiprocessing.Pipe` on which the `multiprocessing.Queue` is built. It is not as flexible as a Queue because it really only supports one producer and one consumer, but that is all you need for your purposes and it is much more performant.

When function `Pipe([*duplex*])` is called, it returns a pair (`conn1`, `conn2`) of `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` objects representing the ends of the pipe. If *duplex* is `False`, then the pipe is unidirectional: `conn1` can only be used for receiving messages and `conn2` can only be used for sending messages. For this application you only need unidirectional connections. The idea is to pass to function `read` as the second argument a *list* of connections on which it should broadcast the data it has read to the various processes that need to process it.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time

def read(pathList, conn_list):
    for path in pathList:
        value = readFunc(path)
        # simulate lots of data:
        for _ in range(1_000):
            for conn in conn_list:
                conn.send(value)
    for conn in conn_list:
        conn.send(None)

def calc0(src_conn, des_conn):
    while True:
        data = src_conn.recv()
        if data is None:
            break
        des_conn.send(calcFunc0(data))
    des_conn.send(None)

def calc1(src_conn, des_conn):
    while True:
        data = src_conn.recv()
        if data is None:
            break
        des_conn.send(calcFunc1(data))
    des_conn.send(None)

# dummy functions for testing

def readFunc(path):
    return path

def calcFunc0(data):
    return data.upper()

def calcFunc1(data):
    return data.lower()

def process_results(results, conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv()
        if data is None:
            break
        results.append(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    readPathList = ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee']

    res0_recv, res0_send = Pipe(False)
    data0_recv, data0_send = Pipe(False)
    res1_recv, res1_send = Pipe(False)
    data1_recv, data1_send = Pipe(False)
    results0 = []
    results1 = []
    # start threads to process results
    t0 = Thread(target=process_results, args=(results0, res0_recv))
    t1 = Thread(target=process_results, args=(results1, res1_recv))
    t0.start()
    t1.start()
    readProcess = Process(target=read, args=(readPathList, [data0_send, data1_send]))
    readProcess.start()
    calcProcess0 = Process(target=calc0, args=(data0_recv, res0_send))
    calcProcess0.start()
    calcProcess1 = Process(target=calc1, args=(data1_recv, res1_send))
    calcProcess1.start()
    readProcess.join()
    calcProcess0.join()
    calcProcess1.join()
    t0.join()
    t1.join()
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(len(results0), results0[0], results1[0], elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
5000 AA aa 0.34799909591674805
```

**Update**

If all the various connections make the code a bit difficult to follow, then we can data hide the connections in a class, `Efficient_Queue`, which might lead to code more readily decipherable:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time

class Efficient_Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._recv_conn, self._send_conn = Pipe(False)

    def put(self, obj):
        self._send_conn.send(obj)
        return self

    def get(self):
        return self._recv_conn.recv()

def read(pathList, q_list):
    for path in pathList:
        value = readFunc(path)
        # simulate lots of data:
        for _ in range(1_000):
            for q in q_list:
                q.put(value)
    for q in q_list:
        q.put(None)

def calc0(src_q, des_q):
    while True:
        data = src_q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        des_q.put(calcFunc0(data))
    des_q.put(None)

def calc1(src_q, des_q):
    while True:
        data = src_q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        des_q.put(calcFunc1(data))
    des_q.put(None)

# dummy functions for testing

def readFunc(path):
    return path

def calcFunc0(data):
    return data.upper()

def calcFunc1(data):
    return data.lower()

def process_results(results, q):
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None:
            break
        results.append(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    readPathList = ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee']

    res0_q = Efficient_Queue()
    res1_q = Efficient_Queue()
    data0_q = Efficient_Queue()
    data1_q = Efficient_Queue()
    results0 = []
    results1 = []
    # start threads to process results
    t0 = Thread(target=process_results, args=(results0, res0_q))
    t1 = Thread(target=process_results, args=(results1, res1_q))
    t0.start()
    t1.start()
    readProcess = Process(target=read, args=(readPathList, [data0_q, data1_q]))
    readProcess.start()
    calcProcess0 = Process(target=calc0, args=(data0_q, res0_q))
    calcProcess0.start()
    calcProcess1 = Process(target=calc1, args=(data1_q, res1_q))
    calcProcess1.start()
    readProcess.join()
    calcProcess0.join()
    calcProcess1.join()
    t0.join()
    t1.join()
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(len(results0), results0[0], results1[0], elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
5000 AA aa 0.3409993648529053
```

When `Efficient_Queue` instances are replaced by `multiprocessing.Queue` instances we get:

```
5000 AA aa 0.576676607131958
```

When `multiprocessing.Queue` instances are replaced by *managed* queues (i.e. `m.Queue()` where `m` is `Manager()`), we get:

```
5000 AA aa 2.8409862518310547
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a go below at doing this with **Redis** PubSub as I suggested in the comments.

Note that installing **Redis** is a pretty simple and lightweight process, and it can also easily be run using `docker`, mapping container port 6379 to host's 6379:

```
docker run --name Redis -p 6379:6379 redis:latest
```

Note also that, as **Redis** is networked, you can run publishers and subscribers on different machines.

Note also that you can run as many subscribers, and indeed publishers, as you like without changing the code for either.

Here is the publisher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import redis
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Configurable settings
    host, port = 'localhost', 6379
    topic = 'stuff'
    nMsgs = 20

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[Redis:Publisher] %(levelname)s:%(message)s')

    # Redis connection
    logging.info(f'Running with host={host}, port={port}')
    r = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=0)

    # Test Redis is running
    if not r.ping():
        logging.critical('Redis is not responding')
        sys.exit(1)

    logging.info('Redis is responding')

    # Publish a bunch of messages
    for i in range(nMsgs):
        message = f'Test message {i+1}/{nMsgs}'
        logging.info(f'Published: {message}')
        r.publish(topic, message)

    # Tell subscribers the show is over
    r.publish(topic, 'quit')

    logging.info('Done')
```

And here is the subscriber:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import redis
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Configurable settings
    host, port = 'localhost', 6379
    topic = 'stuff'

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[Redis:Subscriber] %(levelname)s:%(message)s')

    # Redis connection
    logging.info(f'Running with host={host}, port={port}')
    r = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=0)

    # Test Redis is running
    if not r.ping():
        logging.critical('Redis is not responding')
        sys.exit(1)

    logging.info('Redis is responding')
    logging.info(f'Subscribing to topic: {topic}')
    sub = r.pubsub()
    sub.subscribe(topic)

    for message in sub.listen():
        if message['data'] == b'quit':
            logging.info(f'Teardown requested')
            break
        logging.info(f'Received: {message}')

    logging.info('Done')
```

Note that there is also an asynchronous subscriber option, that lets you do other stuff (like run a GUI) and just calls you back whenever a message is received.

**Sample Output - Publisher**

```
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Running with host=localhost, port=6379
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Redis is responding
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 1/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 2/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 3/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 4/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 5/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 6/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 7/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 8/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 9/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 10/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 11/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 12/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 13/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 14/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 15/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 16/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 17/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 18/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 19/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Published: Test message 20/20
[Redis:Publisher] INFO:Done
```

**Sample Output - Subscribers**

```
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Running with host=localhost, port=6379
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Redis is responding
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Subscribing to topic: stuff
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'subscribe', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': 1}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 1/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 2/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 3/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 4/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 5/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 6/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 7/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 8/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 9/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 10/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 11/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 12/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 13/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 14/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 15/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 16/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 17/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 18/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 19/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Received: {'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'stuff', 'data': b'Test message 20/20'}
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Teardown requested
[Redis:Subscriber] INFO:Done
```